# qt_add_qml_module causes dependency cycle

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I started working in Qt Creator, the project has a simple structure as in the image.

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsnPJ.png)

There is main *`CMakeLists.txt`* which looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(RecipeManager VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick Sql)

qt_standard_project_setup()

qt_add_executable(appRecipeManager)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(include)
add_subdirectory(src_gui)

target_include_directories(appRecipeManager PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

target_link_libraries(appRecipeManager
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
    PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Sql
)

set_target_properties(appRecipeManager PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

install(TARGETS appRecipeManager
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
```

and 3 in subdirectories:

- src:

```
target_sources(appRecipeManager PRIVATE
    main.cpp
    managerdb.cpp
    debug_interceptor.cpp
)
```

- include:

```
target_sources(appRecipeManager PRIVATE
    managerdb.hpp
    debug_interceptor.hpp
)
```

- src_gui:

```
qt_add_qml_module(appRecipeManager
        URI RecipeManager
        VERSION 1.0
        QML_FILES Main.qml
)
```

The problem is caused by the *`src_gui CMakeLists.txt`*. There is a *`Main.qml`* file in that directory which I would like to add to the project.

If I move `qt_add_qml_module` to the main CMakeLists and remove `add_subdirectory` it will work, essentially this in main CMakelists works:

```
qt_add_qml_module(appRecipeManager
        URI RecipeManager
        VERSION 1.0
        QML_FILES src_gui/Main.qml
)
```

But I'm looking for a cleaner way to do this, just like I did it with *include* and *src* files, which work fine.

The error I'm getting to be exact is:

```
ninja: error: dependency cycle: appRecipeManager_autogen/timestamp 
-> src_gui/appRecipeManager_tooling 
-> src_gui/.rcc/qmlcache/appRecipeManager_Main_qml.cpp 
-> src_gui/GUI/appRecipeManager.qmltypes 
-> meta_types/qt6apprecipemanager_debug_metatypes.json 
-> meta_types/appRecipeManager_json_file_list.txt 
-> appRecipeManager_autogen/timestamp

14:19:03: The process "/home/roditu/Qt/Tools/CMake/bin/cmake" exited with code 1.
Error while building/deploying project RecipeManager (kit: Desktop Qt 6.5.1 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Build"
```

I tried to include *`Main.qml`* in my application.

How can I achieve this and fix dependency cycle?